# WPF placing a Label at fixed location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF window with a Pan and Zoomable Image. Now I want to have a Label that will display the zoom percentage at a fixed location in the window (eg. at center). The position should not be changed even if I Zoom or Pan the photo.

Here is the XAML of my window:

```
<Window x:Class="ImageViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageViewer"
    Name="mainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Height="600"
    Width="900"
    WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="#FF3C3C6A"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Image Name ="imageContainer"/>
    </local:ZoomBorder>
</Grid> </Window>
```

Now I want to place the following Label in a way that its location never gets changed.

```
<Label Name ="ZoomLabel" Width="150" Height="50"
              Content="100%" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Background="#FF383838" Foreground="#FFEAE4E4" 
              FontWeight="Bold" Opacity="0.75" FontSize="30"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add the label in the same row, column as the zoom border in the grid so that it overlays:

```
<Grid>
    <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Image Name ="imageContainer"/>
    </local:ZoomBorder>
    <Label Name ="ZoomLabel" Width="150" Height="50"
              Content="100%" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Background="#FF383838" Foreground="#FFEAE4E4" 
              FontWeight="Bold" Opacity="0.75" FontSize="30"
              Margin="10,10,0,0"
              />
</Grid> </Window>
```